# Changing height on div in css when resizing page using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm looking for a way to set the height of my div `searchResults` to 100% when I resize down to `col-xs-12`. When the `searchFilter` div shrinks down to `col-xs-12` I hide it and its height is set to 20%. The div below it `searchResults` has a height of 80%, and when I resize down to `col-xs-12` I want to change it's height to 100%.

I tried this in my css but it didn't work.

```
.searchResults .col-xs-12 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I also tried

```
.searchResults > .col-xs-12 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my html and css

```css
.searchFilter {
  height: 20%;
}
.searchResults {
  height: 80%;
}
.searchResults .col-xs-12 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 hidden-xs">
      @*Sidebar*@
      <div id="googleResultMap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
      @*Body content*@
      <div class="searchFilter col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
        hi
      </div>
      <div class="searchResults col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        @*some content here left out*@
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please try rephrasing your question, as I've already read twice and didn't get it.

Comment: Does the container of your `searchResults` div's parent have any `height` set? If no, you're percentage based heights _won't work_.

Comment: I'd like to take a shot at your question but I don't have time right now. But here's my quick explanation on working with percentage heights in CSS. Maybe it will shed some light. Good luck! http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 5):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    /* only size 'xs' and below */
    .searchResults {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used media queries but if I want to set the height to 100% when the div is extra small wouldn't I want to set height to 100% and not 20 in your example above?

Answer (score 3):

H there, What you will need to look at ... use here is **media queries** at each breakpoint.

Use a media query for each size you what to change.

Just use your class **searchFilter** like this...

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
.searchFilter {
height: 100%;
}
}
```

Have a look at this [Bootstrap link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) about media queries.

**Added to here:**

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1krfpgbh/)** for you to look at.
Just resize the window to see the height change at the media breakpoints.
Note I use **vh** and not **%** as I don't know what parent size you are working too here.

[image: media queries resize]

Comment: I tried inserting this into my styles section but the @media isn't found. Do I need to include something?

Comment: Hi there, did you add this to your css file or in your html page? if in your html page did you place the code between `<style> </style>` I will see if I ccan make a Fiddle of this later when I have time.

Comment: I have added a Fiddle link above. Try the fiddle and resize the window. Hope this helps you.